# Prettier breaks line in function definition when it has the type of returned function

Tags: javascript, typescript, coding-style, code-formatting, prettier

I have this function:

```
// before and after prettier

const foo = (a: number) => (b: number) => {
  return a + b
}
```

If I run prettier it will leave everything as is (which is desired behaviour for me).

When I add type of returned function though it breaks a like for some reason.

```
// before prettier

type NestedFuncType = (b: number) => number

const foo = (a: number): NestedFuncType => b => {
  return a + b
}
```

```
// after prettier
type NestedFuncType = (b: number) => number

const foo =
  (a: number): NestedFuncType =>
  (b) => {
    return a + b
  }
```

Is there anything I can do to prevent line breaks? My .prettierc:

```
{
  "printWidth": 120,
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "es5"
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: if you are using VSCode what worked for me was changing directly in settings:
type command comma (CMD ,) or ctrl comma (CTRL ,) to open settings, search for prettier and under Print Width increase the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prettier is [opinionated, on purpose](https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html). You cannot change the way it formats your code, aside from a few exceptions and looking at their [options](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html) doc, it does not mention any option to customize the mentioned behavoir. You might consider dropping prettier and using TS ESLint instead.